# Windows batch script and privileges for working in HomePath

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

Funny thing, but I've been working with bash, etc but never with Windows' batch scripting.

What I am trying to do is rename some directory in my HomePath.
So I simply do:

```
cd %HOMEPATH%
ren dirName newDirName
```

And then I get:

```
Access denied.
```

Is it even possible in Windows XP / 7 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you're already on the correct drive? 
`%HOMEPATH%` only gives you the directory, not the drive.

I'd suggest trying:

```
%HOMEDRIVE%
cd %HOMEPATH%
ren dirName newDirName
```

Comment: I didn't write about it, but yes - I'm all the time in `C` drive. However good point to add it before.

Comment: @hsz: Possibly a silly question, but you've made sure that `%HOMEPATH%` is set to what you expect? By `echo %HOMEPATH%` or similar. And have you tried to do the rename manually, to make sure that there aren't issues with the actual directory being locked in some way?

Comment: Your question was not silly. ;-) Thanks to that I've figured out that the problem is in name of directory - it contains dot on the beggining (like unix hidden files). Is it possible to rename it ? `.old` -> `.new`

Comment: @hsz: That shouldn't be a problem to do from the command line. It's only Windows Explorer that doesn't like file/folder names starting with `.`. This blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/14/8389268.aspx) discusses the reasoning for Explorer not letting you do that.